# Multiple jquery-ui sliders

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having some problems using multiple sliders at the same time.

In the html I have something like:

```
<div id="slider1"></div>
<div id="slider2"></div>
```

And in the javascript:

```
$("#slider1").slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) { alert("slider 1 slided"); }
});

$("#slider2").slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) { alert("slider 2 slided"); }
});
```

Both sliders appear, but when moving slider1 it displays the alert "slider 2 slided". If I add more sliders the behaviour is the same, all sliders call the event for the last registered slider.

Am I missing something or is this a bug in jquery-ui?

This is jquery 1.4.2 with jquery-ui 1.8.6

Comment: I think you'll need to post more of your code, because AFAIK this is not a jqueryui bug and what you've pasted here looks correct.  Can you supply some code on http://jsfiddle.net/ that replicates the problem?

Comment: Yes you are right, it is a problem on my side. I tested the code in jsfiddle cleaning it a little bit and worked. Sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you posted expanded out into a full working example, and everything works correctly. You'll need to post more code that fully duplicates the issue before anyone will be able to help you.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.6/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="slider1"></div>

<br/>

<div id="slider2"></div>

<script>
    $(function(){

        $("#slider1").slider({
            slide: function(event, ui) { alert("slider 1 slided"); }
        });

        $("#slider2").slider({
            slide: function(event, ui) { alert("slider 2 slided"); }
        });

    });
</script>
```